# Android/Java text file read problem

Tags: java, android, text, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm currently trying to read a file from (res/raw) by using an InputStream that I dimension like such:

```
InputStream mStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_text_file_utf_8);
```

I then put that into this method to return the values:

```
public List<String> getWords(InputStream aFile) {

List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
  BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(aFile));          
  try {
    String line = new String();//not declared within while loop
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null ){              
        contents.add(line);
    }
  }
  finally {
    input.close();
  }
}
catch (IOException ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
}

return contents;
```

}

**My problem:** It reads all the values as it should, but say if the file is **104 lines** long, it will actually return a value of something like **134 total** lines with **the remaining 30 lines being full of null**??

**Have checked:** Already using UTF-8 format, and double checked that there are literally **no blank lines within the document itself**...

I thought the way the while loop was written that it couldn't record a line=null value to contents List? Am I missing something here?

Thanks for any constructive information! I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking some simple factoid here though...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create HTML for your information and then parse it.

Comment: Using it for a number of static byte arrays. Not sure where HTML would get me any better performance, other than solving the current problem. I'd then have to rewrite a ton of code to work with HTML instead... Thanks for the suggestion though.